# Will $lookup still be slow if it is joining by _id?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

Suppose that after `$match` stage, 10,000 documents will be passed into a `$lookup` stage. For each of those 10,000 documents, the `$lookup` will need to join based on its `_id`. The foreign field to join by will be indexed and almost unique - as it is made up of `_id`.

Will each `$lookup` for each of the 10,000 documents have O(1) due to the index?

So is it safe to assume that this pipeline will be fast and scalable?

Comment: Never assume, test and verify.

Comment: @Joe But this question seems to be answerable based upon raw first principles, no?

Comment: If all that matters is big O, sure, but at some point the amount of memory, disk bandwidth, connection counts, etc. have a bigger impact on scalability.  So big O is a great tool for getting started, but it would be foolhardy to say that it is safe to assume scalability based solely on big O.